CDCR Replication is not working in solr 8.11.2
 I have setup CDCR IN Azure VM with 3 nodes and 3 zookeeper
`My Solr version is 8.11.2
Zookeeper =v3.6.2
I have setup source and target cluster with below configuration in source, We are not able to see the replicated data in target cluster and getting warning like Log reader for target collection4 is not initialised ,​ it will be ignored. And no error as such
<requestHandler name="/cdcr" class="solr.CdcrRequestHandler">
  <lst name="replica">
    <str name="zkHost">11.0.0.68:2182,11.0.0.69:2182,11.0.0.70:2182/chroot/solr</str>  ==I tried giving 11.0.0.68:2182,11.0.0.69:2182,11.0.0.70:2182 like this as well
    <str name="source">collection4</str>
    <str name="target">collection4</str>
  </lst>

  <lst name="replicator">
    <str name="threadPoolSize">8</str>
    <str name="schedule">1000</str>
    <str name="batchSize">128</str>
  </lst>

  <lst name="updateLogSynchronizer">
    <str name="schedule">1000</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
   <updateLog class="solr.CdcrUpdateLog">
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>

`
`Please help how to resolve this error.
We tried replicating from source to target but it is not happening and not getting as error also .
Warning which we are seeing is  Log reader for target collection4 is not initialised,&#8203
`
